# Global object not retrieved when stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to store a global object in localStorage on page1 which runs for around 4 seconds and then redirects me to a new page eg: page2.

For storing global object in page1 to localStorage I use:

Page1--    xyz.site.com/myCode.html

```
window.my_global_object = {
property1: "abc",
property2: "pqr"
}

window.localStorage["my_storage_vals"] = my_global_object;
```

Page2:   mylocal/page2.html

```
var retrievedObject = window.localStorage["my_storage_vals"];
                            alert(retrievedObject);
```

But still I cannot see my object being stored. It's still undefined. I want to maintain the state of my globalObject on Page2 . Not on page3 or page4 etc .. . I want to save the values only on page2.

Using json.stringify

```
var val = JSON.stringify(my_global_object);
            localStorage.setItem("myVal",val);

var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("myVal");
                            alert(retrievedObject);
```

Comment: localStorage stores everything as a string, you need to JSON.stringify when putting into localStorage and JSON.parse when retrieving

Comment: yeah I tried that as well. But I don't see the value

Comment: It should work as @PatrickEvans said.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown actually that's not correct. Even if you don't use the JSON.parse/JSON.stringify methods, you should be able to read the object in the localStorage stored as a string. The OP is saying the retrieved object is undefined, so that means that there's another kind of problem.

Comment: @appleris are you sure that your page2 is under the same protocol and domain? What are the addresses of the two pages? Include it in your question please.

Comment: if I use JSON.stringify I get O/P as null.

Comment: Is local storage supported on your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that your pages are:

1. `xyz.site.com/myCode.html`
2. `mylocal/page2.html`

The `localStorage` object is bound to the local domain, so `xyz.site.com` will have a totally different `localStorage` than `mylocal`. Hence, if you set a property in the first page and then redirect to another site, the `localStorage` will not be the same anymore, and you'll not have access to your property.

To work around this you should either:

- Put both pages on the same domain
- or call the second page passing some query string in the url
- or implement an `XMLHttpRequest` from the second to the first page.